# remap git checkout to git checkout -b OR git checkout

Tags: git, bash, shell

Is there a way to alias `git checkout` to `git checkout` if the branch exists OR `git checkout -b` if it does not?

Comment: No.  Or, not easily.  You could certainly alias `checkout` to a complicated shell function, but then ever time you made a typo you'd get a new branch, leading to confusion, especially if you didn't notice immediately.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way. Set this up in your user `.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    magic = !sh -c 'git show-ref --verify --quiet refs/heads/\"$1\" && git checkout \"$1\" || git checkout -b \"$1\"' -
```

Usage: `git magic <branch name>`.

It works like this:

1. [`show-ref`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show-ref.html) is used to check if the branch exists. The `--verify` flag is used to specify an exact path, so if you do `git show-ref --verify refs/heads/<branch name>`, you'll only match the branches that are local to your repo, not branches with the same name on any remotes:

   > Enable stricter reference checking by requiring an exact ref path. Aside from returning an error code of 1, it will also print an error message if `--quiet` was not specified.

   `--quiet` makes sure you don't see any error messages that you don't need:

   > Do not print any results to stdout. When combined with `--verify` this can be used to silently check if a reference exists.
2. If `show-ref` exits with code 0, then the branch exists, and the command after `&&` is executed, checking out the branch. Otherwise, `show-ref` exits with non-zero status 1, and the command after `&&` isn't executed, but the one after `||` is, which creates a new branch with that name and checks it out.

I should warn, however, that the alias as written doesn't play well with msysgit bash tab completion of branch names, it causes the following error to happen, and I'm not sure why yet:

```
$ git magic fsh.exe": declare: `_git_'git': not a valid identifier
```

If you don't try to tab-complete the branch name, the alias will still work ok. I found this Stack Overflow question and answer that might help with the tab complete issue, but I'm not sure: [Git aliases - command line autocompletion of branch names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466991/git-aliases-command-line-autocompletion-of-branch-names).

If you're interested in learning more about how to pass arguments to Git aliases, see [Advanced aliases with arguments](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases#Advanced_aliases_with_arguments) in the [Linux Kernel Git Wiki](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page).

Comment: I'm a little bit tired right now for debugging boolean expression, but in `A && B || C`, if `A` evaluates to `1` I believe B is executed, whereas if it evaluates to `0` is skips to evaluating `C`, since `A && B` is known to be false already. I think you have to swap your `B` and `C` statements.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella in other programming languages, what you say would make sense, but that's not the way it works in Bash, it's the opposite. If you test out the commands in a Bash prompt, you'll see that it works as I've stated.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella if you're interested, you can read about [Lists of Commands in the GNU Bash Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists) to learn about how `&&` and `||` behave in command sequences with exit codes in Bash.

Answer (score 2):

No, not if you want to preserve the command as `git checkout`. Per the git-config [man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html):

> To avoid confusion and troubles with script usage, aliases that hide existing Git commands are ignored.

Other solutions, such as Cupcake's, could work, but you'll have to accept a new name for the alias.